# Laravel object property is null when looping but has value when json_encode()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

My View piece of code:

```
  @forelse ($questions as $question)
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <h4>{{$question->title}}</h4>
                <p>{{Str::limit($question->body, 100)}}</p>
                <span>Asked {{$question->created}} by {{$question->user_name}}</span>
                {{json_encode($question)}}
            </a>
        @empty
            <h2>No questions!</h2>
        @endforelse
```

I'm getting html like this ('...' is ok, that's valid but value is long):

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <span>Asked  by </span> 
            <br>
            {"id":1,"title":"...","path":"...","body":"...","created":"2 hours ago","user_name":"Nash Bogisich","user_id":11}
        </a>
```

As you see, inside html `created` is `null`, as well as `user_name`. But inside json, these props have theirs values. I don't understand how that's possible, please help.

`QuestionResource` is completely plain:

```
class QuestionResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' =>$this->id,
            'title' =>$this->title,
            'path' =>$this->path,
            'body' =>$this->body,
            'created' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(),
//            'modified' =>$this->modified_at,
            'user_name' =>$this->user->name,
            'user_id' =>$this->user_id,
        ];
    }
}
```

I also checked that `created` is really `null`.

```
if ($question->created==null){
                        $created = 'null value';
                    }
```

Yes, `null` value.

`$questions` isn't really array (I think), it's a Laravel collection.

Controllers (I have two, one is for `api` and one is for `web`. `Web` uses `api`.):

API:

```
   public function index()
    {
        // now each transform of question use QuestionResource
        return QuestionResource::collection(Question::latest()->paginate(15));
    }
```

WEB:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $questions = $this->apiController->index();
//        return $questions;
        return View::make('question.index')->with('questions', $questions);
    }
```

Comment: Check your model class, is it included in the hidden array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's stabilish this:

> From PHP's [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php): ...a variable's type is determined by the
>   context in which the variable is used.

Simple example for insight:

```php
$thisIsAnObject = new Object;
echo $thisIsAnObject;
// as echo expects a string, PHP will attempt to cast it to string and it
// will fail with a message similar to: "Object could not be converted to string"
```

However, Laravel, specially in `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, **takes over of this automatic casting** and feeds the context in the type it requires.

Simple example for insight:

```php
$simpleCollection = collect([['key' => 'value'],['key' => 'value']]);
echo $simpleCollection; 
// instead of letting it error, laravel feeds the echo statement with the json
// representation of the collection (which is a string): [{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"}]
// check Illuminate\Support\Collection::__toString() function
```

Laravel does the exactly same for `foreach`:

```php
$collection = Question::latest()->paginate(15);
foreach ($collection as $model) {}
// collection feeds the foreach an array of models for better manusing.
// check Illuminate\Support\Collection::toArray() function
```

**To wrap it all up**, notice that the `QuestionResource`'s mapping takes place inside a `toArray()` function.

So this:

```php
$questionResource = QuestionResource::collection(Question::latest()->paginate(15));
```

if you feed a foreach with the `$questionResource` above, the framework intentions are to feed the foreach with an array of its collection models, ignoring your intention to cast everything to primitive array with `QuestionResource`'s `->toArray()`.

However, for example, if you were to pass `$questionResource` to the `json_encode()` function, which expects a string and does not involves any looping, the framework has no problem resolving the `QuestionResource`'s `->toArray()` first and then casting it to the json representation of the collection.

That's what's happening with your code above.

I will write 2 ways of getting by this issue, from fastest to finest:

### 1) calling ->toArray() to force the casting beforehand

```php
$questions = $this->apiController->index()->toArray(request());
```

```html
@forelse ($questions as $question)
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h4>{{$question['title']}}</h4>
        <p>{{Str::limit($question['body'], 100)}}</p>
        <span>Asked {{$question['created']}} by {{$question['user_name']}}</span>
    </a>
@empty
    <h2>No questions!</h2>
@endforelse
```

### 2) create an accessor for `created` and `user_name` fields in your Question model

```php
class Question extends Model
{
    // $this->created
    public function getCreatedAttribute()
    {
        return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
    }

    // $this->user_name
    public function getUserNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->user->name;
    }
}
```

Like so, you are persisting those fields, by having them available everywhere there's an instance of the Question model. Of course, that includes `QuestionResource`.

```php
class QuestionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'path' => $this->path,
            'body' => $this->body,
            'created' =>  $this->created,
            // 'modified' => $this->modified_at,
            'user_name' => $this->user_name,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id
        ];
    }
}
```

```html
@forelse ($questions as $question)
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
        <h4>{{$question->title}}</h4>
        <p>{{Str::limit($question->body, 100)}}</p>
        <span>Asked {{$question->created}} by {{$question->user_name}}</span>
        {{json_encode($question)}}
    </a>
@empty
    <h2>No questions!</h2>
@endforelse
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the first way seems more logical and common.

Comment: tomorrow morning I'll check this, thanks for piece of hope)

Comment: Your second solution is working, thanks. But your first solution isn't working: `toArray()` takes $request parameter, so I'm getting the 'too few arguments error'. If I pass null, then I'lll get the 'try to access property on null' error.

Comment: I updated the answer with the right code for the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting a bit confused by the API and Web responses.

First you define the `QuestionResource` API resource, that's fine and you put the `created` attribute correctly.

If you then look at your view file, you are iterating over a collection where each object is a `QuestionResource` object type.

To get the attribute you want you should print out `{{ $question->created_at->diffForHumans() }}` as you are still interacting *magically* with a `Question` model.

#### Quick in-depth explaination

When using API resources you should keep in mind that the `PHP Object -> JSON string` conversion happens as later stage after your controller have hadled the request and before the router componen send out the response to the user, if you call your method from another one, you still haven't been through the json transforming process as it is eventually part of a later stage in the core code.

This means that the `$question` return value you are getting from `$this->apiController->index()` call, would give you a collection of `QuestionResource`, not a json string of the response.

To understand how you can still access the `Question` model even if you have an array of `QuestionResource` objects, you have to take a look at the `JsonResource` class in the laravel core.

Every API resource class in laravel inherits from it. This class uses the `DelegateToResource` trait (this one is defined as well in Laravel's core) which defines this method:

```php
/**
 * Dynamically get properties from the underlying resource.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->resource->{$key};
}
```

This means that when you have a `$question` object that is of type `QuestionResource` you can still access the underlying resource by simply "pretending" your resource object is a question, as it will act like so and would automatically forward all the method calls and attribute read to the Question model.

If you are questioning where you did tell the `QuestionResource` to wrap the `Question` model in itself, you did it in the return instruction of your index method:

```php
return QuestionResource::collection(Question::latest()->paginate(15));
```

You can see this return instruction as a "simple" wrapping of each `Question` model you pass as an argument in a bigger object (the `QuestionResource` class) that adds a method to represent the Question as an array that will be therefore used to converted the model to json at a later stage (as I mentioned eariler).

So to retrive fields correctly in your `@foreach` loop you have to refer to your model attributes' names, not the ones you defined as a return for the `toArray()` method, as that would be executed at a later stage.

**So, why does `{{json_encode($question)}}` output the fields defined in the resource?**

Because `JsonResource` class implements the PHP's `JsonSerializable` interface, this means it implements the `jsonSerialize` method (defined by the interface) to force the json conversion.

When you call `json_encode` method, php will recognize that `$question` implements that interface and therefore is serializable, so it call the `jsonSerialize` method and get the desired string.

As a result you get the api resource output and converted to json, and that output have the fields you defined in the `QuestionResource` class

Comment: Ok, I think I got most it. So, the variant of `$questions = $this->apiController->index()->toArray();` (like Welder Lourenço recommended) not working and that's OK, I need to specify `get-`accessors in my `Question` model? Did I get you right?

Comment: You could use accessors or use directly in your views: `$question->created_at->diffForHumans();` to get the `created` value and `$question->user->name` to get the user name. Either way is fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mdexp answer and @Welder Lourenço.

These solutions worked for me:

1. Just call `json_encode` and `json_decode` in my web `QuestionController`. Very simple, do not produce much overhead. But it's a workaround.
2. Specify property get-accessors in `Question` `Model` class. Subtle. And the `Model` class is the right place to define accessors. Now I do use that solution.

Code for #1:

```
public function index()
{
    $str = json_encode($this->apiController->index());
    $questions = json_decode($str);

    return View::make('question.index')->with('questions', $questions);
}
```

Code for #2:

```
// in Question model class...

// $this->created
public function getCreatedAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}

// $this->user_name
public function getUserNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->name;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use the #2 method as it makes no sense to me to json_encode and json_decode the array just to get the same values you would get by using the accessors

Comment: I agree with mdexp

Comment: I'm using #2 method because Model class is the right place to define things like accessors. It's really more subtle and common, thank you for complete explanation.

Comment: Glad I could to help

Comment: @WelderLourenço, what would we do without you kind guys)))